# Taking out only integers to sum and create an average python

Tags: python, list, sum, average

Hi my output for a function when printed is

```
average = ['2.06556473829 is the average for a', 
           '1.48154269972 is the average for b', 
           '1.56749311295 is the average for c',
           '2.29421487603 is the average for d', 
           '1.51074380165 is the average for e', 
           '1.46997245179 is the average for f', 
           '1.15950413223 is the average for g', 
           '1.94159779614 is the average for h', 
           '1.48236914601 is the rainfall average for i',
           '1.2914600551 is the average for j']
```

What i want to do is take only all the whole numbers in the list i.e 2.06555, 1.222 and so on. 
sum them all and then divide the sum by the number of items in the list and print the result

Currently I have a total variable

```
total= sum(int(average))/len(average)
print total
```

However my code doesnt seem to allow me to pick out all the integers and sum them. Is there anyway I can pick out only the integers to sum them and then get the average?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you mean "real numbers" not "whole numbers"

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> average = ['2.06556473829 is the average for a', '1.48154269972 is the average for b', '1.56749311295 is the average for c', '2.29421487603 is the average for d', '1.51074380165 is the average for e', '1.46997245179 is the average for f', '1.15950413223 is the average for g', '1.94159779614 is the average for h', '1.48236914601 is the rainfall average for i', '1.2914600551 is the average for j']
>>> avgs = [float(x.split()[0]) for x in average]
>>> sum(avgs)/len(avgs)
1.626446280991
```

To get average of `int` values of the numbers in the list:

```
>>> avgs = [ int(float(x.split()[0])) for x in average]
>>> sum(avgs)/float(len(avgs))
1.2
```

you can also use `regex` to just get integers:

```
>>> import re
>>> [ int(re.search(r'\d+',x).group(0)) for x in average]
[2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```